# back button in the appbar after succesful login(I didnt use navigation)

Tags: flutter, authentication, build, stack

There is a Back button in the appbar on the page that appears after successful login.
In many similar questions, people used Navigator, but I didn't use Navigator.
So I think the problem is the fact that the screen is stacked, not the navigator.
I think it would be better to initState or SetState rather than build, but I don't know what to do.

To tell you about my app, the login screen doesn't come out as soon as I turn on the app. (log in screen is not 1st screen.)
If you enter Page5 of the bottom navigation bar and press the login button, the signup screen appears,
and after successful login, go back to Page1 of bottomnavigaitonbar on HomePage.

I easily implemented the login screen using the firebaseui package.

Thank you in advance for your reply.

the below is Page5.dart

```
class Page5 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page5({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Page5> createState() => _Page5State();
}

class _Page5State extends State<Page5> {
  final providerConfigs = [EmailProviderConfiguration()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null
        ? Page5_null()
        : Page5_on();
}
}
```

the below is authentication.dart

```
class Authentication extends StatelessWidget {
  const Authentication({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) { 
          return SignInScreen(
            providerConfigs: [EmailProviderConfiguration()],);
        }
        return  HomePage();
    );
  }
}
```

the below is homepage.dart

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var _index = 0;
  final _pages = [
    Ppage1(),
    const Page2(),
    const Page3(),
    const Page4(),
    const Page5(),
  ]; ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Always remove all previous screen when you navigate to home screen after login, I suggest you to use,

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)  =>LoginScreen()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The firebaseui package makes your life more easy to implement, but you dont know how to proceed with some questions.
But to solve your case, I think removing the leading Icon from the AppBar gonna solve.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the back button in the AppBar you just need to pass

```
automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
```

And remember to use `Navigator.pushReplacement()` instead of `Navigator.push()` to remove all stack and push, hope this work

Comment: I used the navigator pushReplacement, but it makes error 'The return type 'Future<dynamic>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context'.... So i added 'return Container', and the red screen 'setstate() or markneedsbuild() called during build~'.. what can i do?